# Scanning a file for a signature (using fread)

Tags: c, fread

The point of the function is to get 2 file streams, a signature, and a scanned file.
It's supposed to scan the scanned file, and if the signature is in it it'll return 1 (file infected).
I tried using the same file as both parameters and it still returned 0, I tried debugging and I can't get the problem.

(sizeOfFile function returns the size of the file in bytes)

```
int scanFile(FILE* signatureFile, FILE* scannedFile)
{
    const size_t signatureSize = sizeOfFile(signatureFile);
    const size_t scannedFileSize = sizeOfFile(scannedFile);
    size_t l1 = 0;
    size_t l2 = 0;
    unsigned char currChar = ' ';
    unsigned char currSignatureChar = ' ';
    int i = 0;
    unsigned char signatureFirstChar = fread(&signatureFirstChar, 1, 1, signatureFile);
    if (scannedFileSize >= signatureSize)
    {
        while ((l1 = fread(&currChar, 1, 1, scannedFile)) != 0)
        {
            if (currChar == signatureFirstChar)
            {
                fseek(scannedFile, -1, SEEK_CUR);
                fseek(signatureFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
                currSignatureChar = signatureFirstChar;
                while (currChar == currSignatureChar)
                {
                    if ((l1 = fread(&currChar, 1, 1, scannedFile)) != 0 && (l2 = fread(&currSignatureChar, 1, 1, signatureFile)) != 0)
                    {
                        i++;
                        if (i == signatureSize)
                        {
                            return 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: It is reasonable to assume the size of a signature file fits in a `size_t` and to determine its length prior to comparing.  The size of the scanned file need not fit in a `size_t`, nor does it need to be determined prior to comparing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fread()` function returns the number of objects read. You are assigning that return value to your `signatureFirstChar` when you do

```
unsigned char signatureFirstChar = fread(&signatureFirstChar, 1, 1, signatureFile);
```

change it to

```
unsigned char signatureFirstChar;
fread(&signatureFirstChar, 1, 1, signatureFile);
```

Comment: good answer, except the returned value from `fread()` should be checked (it this case it should be the same as the 3 parameter,  I.E. 1.  Any other returned value indicates an error, like EOF or signal occurred or ...